# MySQL -> RESTful API

Tags: sql, mysql, web-services, rest

Is there anything out there that given a MySQL database can create RESTful webservice endpoints? I'm ok with it doing stupid basic things to start with, as long as the data model is tunable after.

For bonus points it could understand foreign keys to join data, and create searching endpoints for indexed columns.

Answer (score 2):

[PHP REST SQL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phprestsql/) might be a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

There is [DBSlayer](http://code.nytimes.com/projects/dbslayer), which provides a "JSON over HTTP" interface to MySQL. It doesn't have a REST interface, though.

Comment: This link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [restSQL](http://restsql.org). It's an open-source, ultra-lightweight persistence layer. It's a got enough for basic CRUD and a little bit of basic filtering support.

It has built in support for MySQL and PostgreSQL, but is architected to be extended to other RDBMSes. It runs in standard JEE containers, e.g. Tomcat, or is bundled as a Docker container.

You can take it for a spin using the sandboxed instance and explore the docs at http://restsql.org.